# Using Winform, delete a record from sql server and also check for a file to see if one exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a 'delete' form for my program where a user can input a record key and it'll delete the entire record.  The record key is my primary key.  Located in my database is a field called 'resumelink.'  The resume link just has the name of a file plus an extension, example 'Doc100.pdf.'  When I enter in a record key into my delete form, I want it to check first to see if there exists a file like what's in the resumelink field.  And if there is, it will delete it.  If not, it'll just continue to remove the record in it's entirety.

I know about using File.Exists but how do I use the resumelink field for that particular record key?  Below is my code for my delete button.  It's simple.

```
                        using (SqlCommand deleteCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        deleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM HRresume WHERE recordkey = @recordkey";
                        deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recordkey", recordkeyAdd.Text);
                        deleteCommand.Connection.Open();
                        deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Resume Deleted.");
                        connection.Close();
                        this.Dispose();
                    }
```

Comment: Is `resumelink` in the same `HRresume` table? If so, you'll need to do a `SELECT` first to get the `resumelink` and then you can use `File.Exists` assuming, of course, that all this is running on the same server.

Comment: Yes, resumelink is in the HRresume table. So I can use File.Exists(path + "@resumelink") in order to check for the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, this `resumelink` is another column in this `HRresume` table.
Assuming this is SQL Server, you could use a query such as this:

```
DELETE FROM HRresume 
OUTPUT DELETED.resumelink
WHERE recordkey = @recordkey
```

This will delete the record, and output the value of the `resumelink` column at the same time.

Change `deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` to `deleteCommand.ExecuteReader()` and read the file name from there.

Comment: Awesome. My boss just told me to go so I can't try this just yet but I will definitely come back to this on Friday. Thank you, sir!

Comment: So I'm trying this out today.  I'm still a bit confused.  I have the 'output deleted.resumelink' in my sql query, but how do I put that into the 'file.exists' if statement? Because I would think I would write 'if(file.exists(path + @"resumelink))' but that doesn't seem right. Could you point me into the right direction again?